# Filtering or Importing data for specific date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was wondering if anyone knows if it's possible to import a data, in a sort of a COUNTIF function but only for the data dated today?

I have 2 sheets, Attendance and Department.

[image: Department Tab]
In the Department tab, I have a list of employee's in column A. In column B and so on, I have a drop down option to select which department they're are stationed for each day. Each column represent a day, B being the 1st, C being 2nd, ... and so on. The header for  each column has the day for the day as well.

[image: Attendance Tab]

On the attendance sheet, I have the list of Department in column A and in B, it is used to record how many employee are stationed at that department. I also have the day for the day on this sheet on A1.

Is it possible that when I change the date, the number of employee stationed in each department will change according to the date?

Is it possible to do this with just functions?

I've tried using the COUNTIF function, but I've found that I will have to change the range on a daily basis.

Comment: Bit understood about your question ! If you provide some sample snaps, will help us to us !

Comment: Pictures attached. Basically I want something like a COUNTIF function in order to count how many employees are stationed in a department for the date. B3:P7 is an in-cell drop down menu to select which department the employees are placed for the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question can be solved by SUMPRODUCT function. See below solution picture:

[SOLUTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzQ3U.png)

Just to quickly explain my solution, I gave a name to the date on the Department sheet, called it '**Date_Lookup**'; and I gave a name to the dates on the Attendance sheet, called it '**Date_List**'. Names will simplify my formula especially when referencing across worksheets.

You will eventually find a lot of COUNIF scenario can be solved by SUMPRODUCT and this is just one example. SUMPRODUCT can do a lot IFs than COUNTIFS can do. In your case there are two criteria, one is which department did an employee attend to, and the other is on which date did the employee attend to that particular department. So my SUMPRODUCT formula can be understood as:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('from the list of dates'='the particular date I want to see')*('from the full attendance record'='how many employees went to the given department'))
```

Let me know if you have difficulties understand my answer. A good 1 hour read through some online articles regarding SUMPRODUCT will help.

Cheers :)

Comment: I tried using SUMPRODUCT before but it returned a #VALUE error. Looked like it only worked after I named the range as per suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Use The Function:** in B4 of Attendance Tab

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Department!" &ADDRESS(3,MATCH($A$1,Department!$A$2:$P$2,0)) & ":" &ADDRESS(6,MATCH($A$1,Department!$A$2:$P$2,0))),$A4)
```

**Results: Attendance Tab**

[image]

**Department Tab:**

[image]

I have used all the references as in the screenshots, you can change them if they are different in your sheet.

Comment: Great ! Excel Mastro Mikku ! @Jme Sekaiichi here is the required formula exactly that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your first step would be to use a function to work out in which column the entered date appears. So in your Department sheet you enter a date in A1, then set B1 to:

`=IFERROR(MATCH(A1, Attendance!2:2, 0), 0)`

I use the IFERROR as I don't like seeing errors on my sheet. Assuming the result isn't zero, use a COUNTIF looking for the department letter in a range in the result column. I'd simply use on OFFSET to get the right range, but sticklers would tell you to find a different way of doing it. So long as your spreadsheet isn't going to increase in size to a massive complexity, OFFSET is fine.

Comment: If you didn't want to use OFFSET, you can use INDEX like this: `=COUNTIF(INDEX(Attendance!$3:$7,,$B$1),$A4)` for B4.